# invalid command name "GoddardStreaming"

Tags: ns2

guys pls help me with this. I followed all the steps i found on installing this application. The installation is working fine yet still i got this error when running the test file.

```
    invalid command name "GoddardStreaming"
    while executing
"GoddardStreaming create _o92 _o3 _o16 _o19 TCP 1000 0"
    invoked from within
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {
delete $o
return ""
}
global errorInfo
error "class $..."
    (procedure "new" line 3)
    invoked from within
"new GoddardStreaming $ns $node_s(0) $node_r(0) TCP 1000 0"
    invoked from within
"set gs(0) [new GoddardStreaming $ns $node_s(0) $node_r(0) TCP 1000 0]"
    (file "test-goddard.tcl" line 54)
```

this is just the test file, so i guess tht i'm not supposed to get this error.